Flutter not refreshing instantly on Xiaomi devices having HyperOS 2
I have a Flutter app, working for months on multiple devices smoothly, I use Provider for sharing resources, like theme, across app, this is my code to change to darkmode:
Future<void> darkModeSwitchTouched(bool value) async {
    final theme = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context, listen: false);
    theme.setTheme(value ? darkTheme : lightTheme);
    setState(() {
      darkMode = value;
    });
  }

It's working on all devices, but not on devices having Xiaomi HyperOS 2, where the screen does not refresh to/from dark mode, until I do some sort of full screen refresh, like screen rotation.
Any suggestion?
